# How to Run Mule Standalone Community Edition on windows 64 bit machine

Tags: mule

I am currently having an issue with running mule-standalone-3.4.0 on a windows 64 bit machine below is the issue.

> ***> Launching a JVM... Starting the Mule Container... Wrapper (Version
>
> > 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
> >
> > WARNING - Unable to load the Wrapper's native library because none of
> >     the
> >               following files:
> >                 wrapper-windows-x86-64.dll
> >                 wrapper.dll
> >               could be located on the following java.library.path:
> >                 C:\Users\jdudla\%LD_LIBRARY_PATH%
> >                 C:\Mule\mule-standalone-3.4.0\lib\boot
> >               Please see the documentation for the wrapper.java.library.path
> >               configuration property.
> >               System signals will not be handled correctly.***

Has anyone else had this issue and corrected it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem was fixed by installing a 32 bit JVM.  Mule Standalone CE only works with 32bit. Mule enterprise works with 64bit...

**>   Mule CE ship with community version of the Tanuki Wrapper. The

> Community version of Tanuki wrapper does not support windows 64 bit.
>   http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/doc/english/download.jsp#downloadNote2
>   To run on windows 64 bit you will have to use Mule EE.**

So to run Standalone on a 64bit machine install a 32bit JVM and it will run fine.

Comment: This worked for me (install x86 JDK 7). Also had to reduce `wrapper.conf` setting for `wrapper.java.maxmemory` to 512

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a 64 bit JVM installed. Type java -version from a command line.

```
c:\> java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

You need to install the a 64 bit JVM or use the 32 bit Mule distro.

Comment: Here's my setup... Any other thoughts.. all ideas are welcome

java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: Odd, you sure you don't have another JVM installed that Mule may be trying to use?

Comment: I verified I only have one JVM running as well as one environment variable set...

Comment: Can you run other java applications?

Comment: Yes all other java applications run fine... However a colleague of mine is running mule on a 64 machine with a 64 JVM but the mule  standalone refernces this... a 32bit OS                                  
JDK: 1.7.0_45 (mixed mode)                                         
OS: Windows 7 - Service Pack 1 (6.1, x86)                          

Whereas the "problem machine" mule references                                                                      
JDK: 1.7.0_45 (mixed mode)                                         
OS: Windows 7 - Service Pack 1 (6.1, amd64)